# Wix 4: How to run console application referenced from the setup project

Tags: c#, .net-core, wix, custom-action, wix4

I've a Wix 4 setup project (in c#).
This project has a reference to a .Net 6 C# console application library.
I'd like to run the .exe of the application library from my Wix 4 setup.
I can't create a CustomAction project because I've to use only .Net 6

I've created a 'CustomAction' tag but I don't know how to call the .exe file.

This is a small example:

Package.wxs:

```
... 
<CustomActionRef Id="CA_ExecDbSetup"/>
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='CA_ExecDbSetup' Before='InstallFinalize' Condition='NOT Installed'/> 
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
...
```

```
<Fragment>
<SetProperty Id="CA_ExecDbSetup"
             Before ="CA_ExecDbSetup"
             Sequence="execute"
             Value="Namespace.ExecDbSetup.exe" /> (--The setup doesn't know where this file is.)

<CustomAction Id="CA_ExecDbSetup" BinaryRef="Wix4UtilCA_$(sys.BUILDARCHSHORT)" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

</Fragment>
```

Thanks